# How to get the minimum price of the candle on which the was opened?

Tags: position, pine-script, pine-script-v5, price, pine-script-v4

Pine Script

How to make a link to the candle on which I entered the trade in Pine Script?
I need to get the low of the candle on which the trade was opened in order to put a stop loss there.

I tried to find a solution in the Pine Script reference, but it was not successful.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a variable that triggers your entry. Soemthing like `entry_condition`. You just need to use this variable to check if your entry condition is `true` and store the `low` price in a `var` variable.

```
var float stop_loss_price = na
stop_loss_price := entry_condition ? low : stop_loss_price // If it is a new entry, store the low price. Keep its old value otherwise
```

You might want to reset this variable when you exit a position.

Also, you need to make sure that your `entry_condition` does not become `true` while you are already in a trade. Otherwise, it will update your stop loss price in the middle of a trade.